# Setting of model attribute which lists all related items

Tags: python, django

My models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to set new attribute `'choices'` to Question model so it lists all Choices related to the question. It should be something like `"choices = X.choice_set.all()?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices')
```

To have backward relation also. 
And, Yes you can add it attribute like Property,
from django docs:

> Also known as “managed attributes”, and a feature of Python since
>   version 2.2. This is a neat way to implement attributes whose usage
>   resembles attribute access, but whose implementation uses method
>   calls.

```
@property
def choices:
 return self.choice_set.all()
```